# Building a node image: Error response from daemon: dockerfile parse error line 15: unknown instruction: CMD["NODE",

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I am trying to build a docker image for an app that uses yarn dependencies. I have this error when I run

```
docker build . -t [name]
```

It starts building, but then I get this error.

Error response from daemon: dockerfile parse error line 15: unknown instruction: CMD["NODE",

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install

COPY package*.json ./
COPY . .

RUN npm install --global yarn
RUN yarn install

EXPOSE 3002

CMD["node", "app.js"]
CMD["yarn", "start"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried changing the Dockerfile lines. Is there a different way for building yarn apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
CMD["node", "app.js"]
CMD["yarn", "start"]
```

in

```
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

You missed the space between `CMD` and `[`.